# How to solve different ros::Time error message

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, rostime, timestamp, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a total of N. 7 `.csv` files. Those files are the result of N.7 sensors mounted on an underwater system. After packing both custom and standard messages according to available documentation and playing them in a `test.bag` file I am able to see the majority of them being broadcasted.
Every file is composed of a different type of column but there is the same column in every file, which is `timestamp`.

**The procedure**

I am showing here N.3 print screen to replicate the problem.

The **first file** is composed of N.4 columns as it is possible to see below:

[image: pressure_temperature_depth_timestamp]

The **second file** is composed of N.3 columns as it is possible to see below:
[image: altitude]

The **third file** I am showing is composed of 18 columns but I am showing only the last columns (that has the timestamp) as it is possible to see below:

[image: usbl]

The way I am packing all the customized and non-customized `ROS` messages is shown below, and it is done in the same way for all the N.7 files. So for brevity I am only including one that is related to the **first file** shown above. Here is the most important part of the code:

**keller_reader.h**

```
#include "csv.h"
#include <string>
#include "ros_float/pressure.h"
#include "ros_float/depth.h"
#include "ros_float/temperature.h"
struct KELLER_DATA
{
    unsigned long timestamp;
    double depth;
    double temperature;
    double pressure;
};

class Keller_reader
{
public:
  Keller_reader(std::string filename);
  bool nextLine();
  KELLER_DATA keller_data;
  sensor_msgs::FluidPressure pressureMsg;
  ros_float::pressure pMsg;
  ros_float::temperature tMsg;
  ros_float::depth dMsg;

private:
  io::CSVReader<4> keller_reader;
  unsigned int msgNumKeller;
  void packPressureMsg();
  // Custom Pressure Message
  void packCustom_TemperatureMsg();
  void packCustom_DepthMsg();
};
```

**keller_reader.cpp**

```
#include "keller_reader.h" 
Keller_reader::Keller_reader(std::string filename):
    keller_reader(filename)
{
    msgNumKeller = 0;
    keller_reader.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column,
                              "timestamp", "depth", "temp","pressure");
}

bool Keller_reader::nextLine()
{
    if(keller_reader.read_row(keller_data.timestamp, keller_data.depth,
                              keller_data.temperature, keller_data.pressure))
    {
        packPressureMsg();
        packCustom_TemperatureMsg();
        packCustom_DepthMsg();
        msgNumKeller++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Keller_reader::packPressureMsg()
{
    double doubleTime = double(keller_data.timestamp)/1e6;
    ros::Time stamp(doubleTime);
    pMsg.header.stamp = stamp;
    pMsg.header.frame_id = "/pressure";
    pMsg.header.seq = msgNumKeller;
    pMsg.fluid_pressure = keller_data.pressure;
}

void Keller_reader::packCustom_TemperatureMsg()
{
    // same procedure as above
}

void Keller_reader::packCustom_DepthMsg()
{
   // same procedure as above
}
```

Notice that the timestamp is treated in the same way in all files so that can be brought to a standard readable `ROS` time:

```
    double doubleTime = double(keller_data.timestamp)/1e6;
    ros::Time stamp(doubleTime);
```

Because remember from above that what I have in the `.csv` file is this:

[image: this]

**The Problem**

This approach works well for all N.6 files. However when I do the same with the last file I have very different errors.
The most important part of the code is below:

**usbl_reader.h**

```
struct USBL_DATA
{
    int prop_time;
    double accuracy;
    double e;
    unsigned long ctime;
    double h_reader;
    int remote_id;
    int rssi;
    double n;
    double p;
    double depthUSBL;
    double r;
    double u;
    unsigned long mtime;
    double xPosition;
    double yPosition;
    double zPosition;
    int integrity;
    unsigned long timestamp;
};

class USBL_reader
{
public:
  USBL_reader(std::string filename);
  bool nextLine();

  USBL_DATA usbl_data;
  ros_float::accuracy accuracyMsg;
 // other custom messages
  geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped poseWithCovStamped;

private:
  io::CSVReader<18> usbl_reader; // number of columns of the file
  unsigned int msgNumUSBL;
  void pack_XYZ_Pose_WithCovariance_Msg();

  void pack_Prop_Time_Msg();
  // packing other custom messages 
};
```

**usbl_reader.cpp**

```
USBL_reader::USBL_reader(std::string filename):
    usbl_reader(filename)
{
    msgNumUSBL = 0;
    usbl_reader.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column,
                            "prop_time", "accuracy", "e", "ctime", "h", "remote_id",
                            "rssi", "n", "p", "depth", "r", "u", "mtime",
                            "y", "x", "z", "integrity", "timestamp");
}

bool USBL_reader::nextLine()
{
    if(usbl_reader.read_row(usbl_data.prop_time, usbl_data.accuracy, usbl_data.e,
                            usbl_data.ctime, usbl_data.h_reader, usbl_data.remote_id,
                            usbl_data.rssi, usbl_data.n, usbl_data.p,
                            usbl_data.depthUSBL, usbl_data.r, usbl_data.u,
                            usbl_data.mtime, usbl_data.yPosition, usbl_data.xPosition,
                            usbl_data.zPosition, usbl_data.integrity , usbl_data.timestamp))
    {
        pack_XYZ_Pose_WithCovariance_Msg();
        // packing other messages .... 
        msgNumUSBL++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void USBL_reader::pack_XYZ_Pose_WithCovariance_Msg()
{
    double doubleTime = double(usbl_data.timestamp)/1e6;
    ros::Time stamp(doubleTime);
    poseWithCovStamped.header.stamp = stamp;
    poseWithCovStamped.header.frame_id = "/PoseWithCovariance";
    poseWithCovStamped.header.seq = msgNumUSBL;
    poseWithCovStamped.pose.pose.position.x = usbl_data.xPosition;
    poseWithCovStamped.pose.pose.position.y = usbl_data.yPosition;
    poseWithCovStamped.pose.pose.position.z = usbl_data.zPosition;
}

// other messages implementation
```

**The Error**

The current settings of the `usbl_reader` file above throws the following error when running the `test.bag` file:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rosbag::BagException' what():  Tried to insert a message with time less than ros::TIME_MIN Aborted (core dumped)`

Some possible solution I tried were writing a `global_t_stamp.h` header file that looks like this:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_T_STAMP_H
#define GLOBAL_T_STAMP_H

#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint64_t timestamp_t;
typedef uint64_t ctime_t;
typedef uint64_t mtime_t;
#endif // GLOBAL_T_STAMP_H
```

And substitute the message in the `usbl_reader.cpp` with the following message:

```
void USBL_reader::pack_XYZ_Pose_WithCovariance_Msg()
{
    timestamp_t currentTime = usbl_data.timestamp;
    ros::Time stamp(currentTime);
    poseWithCovStamped.header.stamp = stamp;
    poseWithCovStamped.header.frame_id = "/PoseWithCovariance";
    poseWithCovStamped.header.seq = msgNumUSBL;
    poseWithCovStamped.pose.pose.position.x = usbl_data.xPosition;
    poseWithCovStamped.pose.pose.position.y = usbl_data.yPosition;
    poseWithCovStamped.pose.pose.position.z = usbl_data.zPosition;
}
```

But this time I obtained a different error when running the `test.bag` file see below:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what():  Time is out of dual 32-bit range Aborted (core dumped)`

The last solution I tried was changing the `unsigned long` format of the timestamp with `unsigned int` as below

```
struct USBL_DATA
{
    // data structure
    unsigned int timestamp;
};
```

But this time I got another different error that seems to send the message in `overflow` see below the result after running the `test.bag` file

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'io::error::integer_overflow' what():  The integer "1517940547956428" overflows in column "timestamp" in file "/home/emanuele/Desktop/file.csv" in line "2".`

which in this case as it is possible to see from line 2 of the file is just the beginning of the file:

[image: file3]

I don't understand what is going on and why I am receiving this error if I applied the same exact conversion of the timestamp into a `ROS` readable format as shown below:

```
    double doubleTime = double(usbl_data.timestamp)/1e6;
    ros::Time stamp(doubleTime);
```

Can anyone shed light on this matter and why this is behaving like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322253/how-to-solve-different-ros::time-error-message/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The timestamps in ROS bag files, and by extension your original CSV files, are stored in integer nanoseconds. Therefore, I think your problem is that you are assuming the timestamps are in microseconds when you convert them to a `double` representation. I think if you divide by `1e9` instead of `1e6` it will fix it.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-05-01**:
@robustify, thank you very much, that was exactly what was happening! :)

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2019-05-01**:
You're welcome!